# Automatically populate data from active excel worksheet to another

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a table of targets vs accomplishments per quarter. I have a 1st quarter and 2nd quarter worksheet. What I want to achieve is every time i put data to the 1st quarter on 1st quarter worksheet, it automatically populate the columns/rows in the 2nd quarter worksheet. Please see attached screen shots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Copy. Just updated

Comment: Couldn't you just have a formula in C11 of the second quarter sheet saying `='First quarter'!C11` ?  (Changing the sheet name as appropriate.)  Or maybe `=IF('First quarter'!C11="","",'First quarter'!C11)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have the Q1 cells populated in the Q2 worksheet with the values you enter in Q1 sheet.

Can't you simply put a reference to the cell in Q1?

```
='Q1SheetName'!CellAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use Excel formuar to link value,e.g. in Sheet2 cell C11 `=Sheet1!B11`